# Printing Latex source with a2ps

Tags: printing, latex, a2ps

When I try to print out latex source code with

```
a2ps somefile.tex
```

I get error messages from egrep like

```
egrep: Das Ende des angegebenen Intervalls ist nicht gültig
```

which translates to "the end of the given interval is invalid."
After that texi2dvia4ps tries to compile my tex file and fails.
I can print other source code just fine.
Any idea what's wrong?

Edit: jofels answer fixes the problem with egrep. a2ps still tries to compile my .tex file instead of pretty printing it as source code. Using

```
a2ps --delegate=no somefile.tex
```

stops it (partly) from doing so. Minor commands like \item or \phi are still interpreted instead of printed out as they are in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message (in English "egrep: Invalid range end") comes from a bug in [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/).

Its `/usr/bin/texi2dvi4a2ps` shell script calls `egrep` wrongly:

Instead of

```
echo "$command_line_filename" | egrep '^(/|[A-z]:/)' >/dev/null \
|| command_line_filename="./$command_line_filename"
```

it should be

```
echo "$command_line_filename" | egrep '^(/|[A-Za-z]:/)' >/dev/null \
|| command_line_filename="./$command_line_filename"
```

As the bug is in a shell script, you can fix it easily by just editing the file.

The pattern checks if the filename is absolute (starts with an `/`, relevant on Unix-like systems) or starts with a drive name (e.g. `C:`, relevant only for Windows systems). Otherwise, the filename is prepended with `./`.

Feel free to report this bug upstream or to the distribution you use.

Comment: What does it `grep`? If it is user input that would further limit to ASCII.

Comment: @Sukminder I have extended my answer. The actual pattern is not relevant for Unix-like systems.